# In this situation, Which DB should I use Redis or MongoDB?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, redis, database

I have to handle 12000 objects in Node.js from https://data.detroitmi.gov/Public-Safety/DPD-All-Crime-Incidents-2009-Present-Provisional-/b4hw-v6w2/data for map data. (JSON example : https://data.detroitmi.gov/resource/i9ph-uyrp.json)

I heard that Redis helps to deal with a lot of data. but my friend said that Those are not that big enough to use Redis so It would not worth to use Redis. I've only used mongo before but after I deal with those a bunch of data, I felt I can't handle with normal database. So decided to use something like Redis but not really sure. I would like to here some ideas about it!

Comment: That is not a lot of data and any database will be able to handle it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That basically depends on what you mean by "handle".

Redis is in-memory database, so despite it has (a kind of) persistence layer implemented (regular snapshots on disk), some redundancy support (master-slave with replication), and even features for scalability (autosharding through Redis Cluster) - first and foremost, it's in-memory DB.

Which means: it's excellent in serving reads/writes for relatively small dataset (yours fits perfectly, btw) **blazingly** fast, putting consistency & scalability way behind (setting aside more tricky & flexible features).

If that is your purpose - go for it, but the good practice here (widespread, at least) is having a persistence layer served by another database, whether would it be more traditional ACID-type one (like, relational) or trendy distributed stuff.

PS In general, I personally better stick to first option (RDBMS) for persistence layer - they are way more mature and still outperform document-oriented even being used as advanced key-value store.
Although in real life there are no "general" cases, each is specific, so you're going to evaluate it in details.

PPS Another personal opinion: no Mongo, it's a total misadventure by itself.